# Naming conventions for npm module name

Tags: npm

Many npm module names that I see have the tech name added in front of them like react-native or jquery etc. Since we already provide keywords in package.json file, is there any advantage to following this convention. I ask this because I am about to release a package to npm and appending react-native to the start of the name is making it too long. Also, [the best practices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-best-practices#naming-conventions) do not mention anything regarding appending the technology name.

Comment: It is legally up to you. `keywords` section is for [helping people discover your package as it's listed in npm search](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#keywords). If it was that advantageous, react would name it with some prefix like `facebook-react` etc.

Comment: You may want to be careful when using registered trademarks in your names. (e.g. I wouldn't take the risk of calling it 'microsoft-windows', 'angular-pro', 'react-core' or anything else that could mislead people.)

Answer (score 13):

There is no convention for naming packages with the related tech in the name. Just name it whatever you want as long as it's available and is `in-this-format`.

Answer (score 4):

It's completely up to you, people often do this because it helps make it easier and faster to identify what a package is intended for, this is makes things really easy when scrolling through a package.json file and seeing all the `react-native` packages bundled together in a block.

Some technologies offer websites that let you search through packages related to that application such as gulp and ember which assume a prefix of their respective technology names. But as far as I know, react does not do this.

Ultimately it's up to you, if it's a react only module then perhaps follow the convention and it might yield a few benefits for those using the module. If it's not bound to react or supports multiple platforms, then I'd probably ignore the prefix in favor of easier and more generic branding of the module.

Comment: Hi, if you look at point 5 under this [link text](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/guidelines.md), it suggests adding gulpplugin as a keyword in your package.json, it does not suggest adding "gulp-" as a prefix in the module name. Also, for a react-native app, would I not assume all dependencies to be that of react-native itself, how would bundling be an advantage here ??

Comment: @SaurabhGour fair enough with the gulp thing, perhaps it used to, it's been a while since I've done a gulp package. React-native wise, no not at all. You might bring in all sorts of packages which are to do with things like build tools and other npm utility packages. I'm not super clued up on react-native, but I believe you can pull in things like lodash and pretty much any pure JS package from npm. Ultimately this is an opinionated question, there's no correct answer so you can do what you want and what makes sense to you. It sounds like you've already made a decision?

Comment: Fair enough.. let me see if I can find any specific document around this... I guess probably not.. just want to make sure though.. otherwise I'll accept your answer..